# Find password from open-protected pdf

Tags: pdf, encryption

I got an open-protected pdf from the server but also the decrypted pdf from the other place. The size of the open-protected file is 80MB that is slighter larger than decrypted one 76MB. Does it possible to extract the password by comparing two pdf files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, It's not possible. Passwords will be hashed by default using one-way hash functions like MD5, SHA1, SHA2 etc.

You can **not** determine the password just by using size or comparing the files.